# Why do we get away with these assumptions of scattering theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, scattering, s-matrix-theory, particle-accelerators

The **first questionable** assumption I can think of is: The integration of the Hamiltonian density in the Dyson series is done over an infinite spacetime volume.

Why do we get away with this assumption? All real-world scattering experiments take place in a finite volume over a finite time interval.

My guess: I think the prediction of the theory, in the limit of infinite time duration, just happens to co-incide with the prediction of the theory over a finite time duration. This is because, when we collide particles head-on, "most of the interaction" ends up happening in a tiny amount of time, and the system reaches equilibrium fast. After this, even if we let the system interact over an infinite time, the final prediction wouldn't change.

But, if we didn't collide particles head-on, and instead simply let them be in each others' presence, then I think it should take an indefinite amount of time for the final products to be formed.

Even if the above is correct, it doesn't explain why the integral is done over an infinite 3D space volume.

The **second questionable** assumption I can think of is: We take the initial and final states to be eigenstates of the free Hamiltonian.

Why do we get away with this assumption? The actual particles that we collide in experiments should be "dressed-up" with self-interactions, right? Then how can we assume that the initial  and final states are eigenstates of the free Hamiltonian? Also, Haag's theorem says that the Hilbert space of interacting theories is different from that of free theories. Shouldn't this be taken into account when we decide the representation of the initial and final states?

Comment: Your second assumption is wrong. The initial and final states are eigenstates of the EXACT Hamiltonian, which $behave$ like eigenstates of a free Hamiltonian. More precisely, the assumption is that for every eigenstate $\Phi_\alpha$ of the free Hamiltonian there exists TWO eigenstates $\Psi_\alpha^\pm$ of the exact Hamiltonian such that $e^{-i H t} \int d\alpha f(\alpha) \Psi_\alpha^\pm \to e^{- i H_0 t} \int d\alpha f(\alpha) \Phi_\alpha$ as $t \to \mp\infty$ for all square normalizable wave-packets $f(\alpha)$.

Comment: For your first question, consider that the Compton wavelength of an electron at rest is about $2\times 10^{-12}\ {\rm m}$. The radius of the Atlas detector is about $2\times 10\ {\rm m}$. So there's a dimensionless ratio of $10^{-13}$ which controls effects due to the finite size of the real Atlas detector, from the point of view of an electron at rest (and this factor will be even smaller for the relativistically moving particles in the detector). This may give you an idea of why assuming an infinite volume (essentially replacing $10^{-13}$ with $0$) is a reasonable approximation.

Comment: @Prahar Why two of them? Are you saying that, there exists an eigenstate, for which the time evolution in the distant past limit in the presence of the exact Hamiltonian, resembles the time evolution of the corresponding free Hamiltonian eigenstate in the presence of the free Hamiltonian? Why is this assumption justified given that self-interactions exist even in the distant past limit? Self-interaction does not discriminate between time points. All interacting fields are everywhere at all times.

Comment: @RyderRude - You need two of them to define the $in$ states AND the $out$ states. The $S$-matrix of course is an overlap of the $in$ and $out$ states. You need both sets of states to exist in order for the $S$-matrix to exist. When self-interactions are strong enough to not die off at late times, then usually these interactions change the eigenstate so that this assumption is then valid w.r.t. the new set of eigenstates.

Comment: @Prahar But why would self-interactions diminish at distant times? Fields are present everywhere all the same.

Comment: @RyderRude - For instance, in QCD, you start by writing down a theory of quarks, but they are strongly coupled at late times and indeed, the assumption breaks down. However, the strongly coupled nature of quarks implies that at late times, the appropriate set of states are pions, hadrons, and glueballs instead of quarks. The "free" Hamiltonian of QCD is then supposed to describe these states and NOT quarks (which are not asymptotic states). The second assumption then holds for these bound states, i.e. pions are indeed weakly interacting at late times.

Comment: Fields may be present everywhere, but they become small at late times and long distances, e.g. $\phi \sim \frac{1}{r} e^{-mr}$ for a massive scalar. Self-interactions are proportional to $\phi^2$ so these interactions fall off even faster than the fields so interactions generally become weaker and weaker at late times. Of course, this is a classical argument and might be invalid due to strong quantum effects which is what happens in QCD. But even there, by appropriately moving to the "right" set of asymptotic states (pions, hadrons, glueballs, etc.), this classical statement will hold.

Comment: @RyderRude - The qualitative picture to keep in mind is that energy must be constant as the fields dissipate. The more they spread, the smaller their amplitude must be to account for the spread in energy. The smaller they are in amplitude, the smaller their interactions.

Comment: @Prahar I don't know how this argument carries over to the quantum world of operator fields. I may be forgetting, but I think the self interaction probability amplitude didn't depend on time (in QED)? Also, if fields spread over time, wouldn't they be more concentrated in the asymptotic past?

Comment: @prahar consider writing an answer rather than answering in the comments.

Comment: @RyderRude That's why you need TWO sets of fields. The $out$ fields spread out in the future and the $in$ fields spread out in the past.

Comment: @march  providing premature answers to an implacable argumentative skeptic is playing whack-a-mole. The point of comments is to shame the OP into clarifying/pegging-down  the question.

Comment: @CosmasZachos I guess I don’t see this post plus OP’s comments on it as evidence of being an “implacable argumentative skeptic”, so there must be previous behavior that justifies that? I agree with comments attempting to clarify the question, but *shaming* maybe seems a little much, unless previous behavior by the OP justifies it. Plus, Prahars comments thus far *can* be an answer to the question, even if the OP doesn’t see it that way.

Comment: @march Apologies if I veered into meta in the wrong venue: I'm bailing out with considered prejudice. "Fortunately", the system keeps    records. My sense is a background on standard texts is assumed.

Comment: @CosmasZachos I never do that. I wasn't arguing here. I was asking Prahar for more information. I stopped replying when I felt the doubt had been answered

Comment: So there was a missing fact not,e.g., in Weinberg’s book? Maybe you could summarize it…

Comment: @CosmasZachos I haven't read Weinberg's book. In Klauber's book, he talked about turning off the interaction in distant time using something that looked like a step function. I thought it was weird because interactions always exist all the same. Then Prahar said that the self-interaction amplitude diminishes in distant times. This wasn't in the book as far as I've read it.